# Two arrays, one array to list items, second to sort the first one, php code how to?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I got function that prints out array score which concert clinics:

```
array_id    clinic_id    score_amount
0             1              5
1             2              1
2             3              5
3             5              3
4             8              2
```

And i got another function that prints out array clinics id like this:
This array is for listing all clinics on page,

```
array_id    clinic_id
0              1
1              2
2              3
3              4
4              5
5              6
6              7
7              8
8              9
9              10
```

Now my idea is to make array of clinic_id sorted accordinally to score_amount from first array.
And theen if there is no score_amount for particular clinic_id, just go with order from second array normally.

So results needs to be sorted like:

```
array_id    clinic_id
0              1
1              3
2              5
3              8
4              2
5              4
6              6
7              7
8              9
9              10
```

Comment: what? ......... Also why you need to this via Array and not via DB?

Comment: Can you show us the actual arrays themselves? ([`echo print_r($array, true);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php))

Comment: It could be via DB but I got already written functions wich print out arrays, so i want to make use of already written code. No challange in writting new functions over and over for everything i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a custom comparator,

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
if($a == $b) return 0;   
\\get score returns score or -1 if no score exists
if (getscore($a) == getscore($b) { 
return (index($a) < index($b)) ? -1 : 1;  \\index is index of the number in second array     
}
return (getscore($a) < getscore($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($a, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use an associative array (clinic_id => score_amount) and use [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

Comment: You just beet me to the same answer. But, this would be the best (only?) way to do this

Comment: Not the only way, but I think it's the simplest.